# como corregir este problema: SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)

Tags: php, phpmailer

estuve tratando de enviar un correo, con el siguiente codigo:

```
  `<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  require("PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php");
  require("PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.smtp.php");
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 3; 
  $mail->From = "kevinc******@gmail.com";
  $mail->FromName = "kevin";
  $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // specif smtp server
  $mail->SMTPSecure= "ssl"; // Used instead of TLS when only POP mail is selected
  $mail->Port = 465; // Used instead of 587 when only POP mail is selected 25
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = "kevinc******@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
  $mail->Password = "***********"; // SMTP password
  $mail->AddAddress("herna*******@gmail.com", "hernan"); //replace myname and mypassword to yours
  $mail->AddReplyTo("kevinc******@gmail.com", "kevin");
  $mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
  //$mail->AddAttachment("c:\\temp\\js-bak.sql"); // add attachments
  //$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/11-10-00.zip");

   $mail->IsHTML(true); // set email format to HTML
   $mail->Subject = 'test';
   $mail->Body = 'test';
  if($mail->Send()) {echo "Send mail successfully";}
  else {echo "Send mail fail";} 
 ?>`
```

pero me muestra el siguiente error:

SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 
The following From address failed: kevin*****@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected Send mail fail

porque me estaria saliendo este error?
que debo corregir?

Answer (score 1):

Hola el siguiente codigo me funciono, pero tuve que permitir el acceso a aplicaciones poco seguras de google

```
<?php


require 'PHPMailer-5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "correo@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("noreply@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("youcustomer@gmail.com");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   echo "Message has been sent";
}
```